# Can I go from iOS 7.0.6 to 7.1.2?

Tags: ipad

Is there any way to get to 7.1.2 without going to 8 on my old iPad?

Comment: Nope. There is no way to get 7.1.2. Either stay at 7.0.6 or upgrade to 8.1.1 :)

Answer (score 1):

After release of ios 8 that is no longer possible.

Apple no longer signing iOS 7.1.2, closing the downgrade window.

Apple has finally ceased signing iOS 7.1.2.

This means that you can no longer downgrade to the older firmware from iOS 8.x, or upgrade to it from older versions.